# Get body summary in field's replacement pattern

Tags: views, 8

Is it possible to get the body's summary within a view field's replacement pattern?

What I am doing right now is this:

```
{{ field_icon }}

<div class="description">
    {{ title }}
    {{ body }}
</div>
```

As the body text is too long I tried using `{{ body.summary }}` instead of `{{ body }}` but that didn't work at all..

Could you tell me whether there is a possibility to do this inside of a replacement pattern?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select `Summary or trimmed` as your formatter, then `{{ body }}` will print out your summary.

[image]